# CUDA number of data cannot be divide by the CUDA threads evenly

Tags: cuda

For example, there are two 4-threads, but I have 5 data, the first 0-3 can be mapped to the first 4-threads, how about the rest, it only says there might be a runtime error, but how to fix it?
[image]

I think I ask this question in the wrong direction, now suppose I have

```
perfromwork<<<2,2>>>;
```

Now my dataIndex calculated by this pseudocode is smaller than the number of data elements(N=5), so what to do with the last one (5-2x2=1)? If I use another block for it, it will come across the same problem, the <<<2, 2>>> block will create a larger dataIndex.

Comment: It literally says what to do in the graphic

Comment: It only says must check, how to check?

Comment: If you read more than the first three words of that sentence, you will see it is the pseudocode for *exactly* what you have to do to check

Comment: I edited the question, please take a look, thank you!

Comment: The NVIDIA DLI CUDA course that this graphic comes from gives examples of how to write code to do the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two canonical approaches here.

1. Size the grid to be larger than or equal to the data set size, and make sure to use a "thread check" that prevents unneeded extra threads from doing any work.
2. Use a [grid-stride loop](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/), which allows the grid size to be determined independently from the data set size (if you wish) while still providing correct results.

vector add example kernels for each:

```
__global__ void vectorAdd(float *x, float *y, float *z, int size){

  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < size) // thread check
    z[idx] = x[idx] + y[idx];
}
```

The above kernel does not use a grid-stride loop.  It will require that you size the grid to be larger than or equal to the data set size, in order for all elements to be processed.  That sizing code might look like this:

```
  int size = MY_DATA_SET_SIZE;
  dim3 block(256); // this is threads per block, the choice here is not critical for correctness, but must be 1 or larger and less than or equal to 1024;
  dim3 grid((size+block.x-1)/block.x);
  vectorAdd<<<grid,block>>>(...);
```

A kernel implementing a grid-stride loop to do the same thing might look like this:

```
__global__ void vectorAdd(float *x, float *y, float *z, int size){

  for (int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x; idx < size; idx += blockDim.x*gridDim.x)
    z[idx] = x[idx] + y[idx];
}
```

In this case, grid sizing can be arbitrary (1 or larger) and still yield correct results.

Comment: So suppose you have a rest 3 elements after several strides, the idx is still smaller than the size, so it will perform the +=. then why we don't need if (check) here? Thank you.

Comment: So my question is how to check the idx at the last stride?

Comment: Checking on the last stride is handled by the boolean test that is part of the for loop. When a particular thread strides past the end of the valid data set size, it drops out of the operation. You might wish to read the article I linked on grid stride loop.